# d3v4 programmatically pan and zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3.js v4 and trying to implement a force-directed graph with zoom and pan that centers the camera when clicked on a node. So here's the click event on a node:

```
    var x = (width/2-d.x);
    var y = (height/2-d.y);

    g.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
```

This works as intended but after each click **whenever I try to zoom/pan the camera goes back to the position/zoom it was in before**.

Here's my zoom handler:

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
zoom(svg);
function zoomed() {
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```